# Activate spring tooling on java project in eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-juno

I have a eclipse juno with jboss tools 6 and OEPE tools installed on.

My colleagues gave me a project using spring 2.5 and jsf 1.2  but eclipse sees it as a simple java project. So from properties -> project facets I activated web module and JSF support.

When I go to activate spring support it asks to download a spring library and to craeate spring-config.xml.... The problem is that I already have a spring config xml with a custom name and also all spring libs installed.

The question is : how can I make eclipse recognize the existing spring config files in order to activate all the spring tools ? (they are grayed now)

Thank you

Comment: the project is Maven or Ant build?

Comment: this project is ant build only

Comment: k, how you imported to eclipse? Existing Projects?

Comment: yes , imported as existing. They use that as a simple Java project! They do not use tools ... I'll prefer to use instead